# how to add wild card?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, t-sql

Hi i am new programmer asp.net and vb.net. I wanted using wild card to search engine.
i am puzzled put  wild card (%).

```
 Protected Sub search()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cls As New Class1

        ds = cls.returndataset("select * from student where Nama_Depan like '" & nama.Text & "' ")

        viewatt.DataSource = ds
        viewatt.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm really sorry if this has been asked before.

Comment: Your question is not about ASP nor VB. The question is about your SQL database syntax!

Comment: Please, before you implement anything like this anywhere, research "SQL Injection". Simple code such as this is very exploitable. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already pointed out

```
select * from student where Nama_Depan like '%" & nama.Text & "%'
```

is the correct way to use wildcards

Here is a link to the W3Schools tutorial on SQL wildcards: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp
I would suggest you have a quick read through, the W3schools articles are usually really good.

This however is a really bad way to execute SQL commands from your code,  someone could quite easily inject some SQL code into your textbox and when your query is executed it could destroy your database.

As an exaple if someone entered `'; DROP TABLE * --`  into your textbox, this would allow your first query to run, then it would drop all your tables.

It is really easy to get around this by using parameterised queries or stored procedures. Personally I would favour using Stored Procedured and you can do so like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
(
   @param1 VARCHAR(50)
)
AS 
BEGIN
   select * from student where Nama_Depan like '%"'+@param1+'%'
END
```

You would then just need to edit your VB code to call the stored procedure rather than executing the SQL command.

The other advantage of using a stored procedure is that they perform slightly faster and are more efficient, this is because when you pass some SQL to the database it has to compile it into a sql command to execute, stored procedures are already stored on the database and so do not need to do this.

There are also some added security benefits to using a stored procedure rather than just transmitting a SQL statement, If anyone were to intercept your SQL statement on its way across the network / internet they could gain some insight into your database structure. With a stored procedure all they could possibly intercept is the procedure name and some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    Protected Sub search()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim cls As New Class1

    ds = cls.returndataset("select * from student where Nama_Depan like '%" & nama.Text & "%' ")

    viewatt.DataSource = ds
    viewatt.DataBind()

End Sub
```